# "Gestures them to follow", is this gramatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, indirect-objects

*"Come, let us talk elsewhere" - she gestured them to follow.*

I've read that "gesture to", "gesture for" and "gesture prep." are correct in different contexts, but the only one that feels kind of right for the example sentence is "she gestured to them to follow", which reads really clunkily.

I've also asked around, but got mixed results claiming with certainty both that this form is correct, and that it isn't.

Is the original version correct gramatically, or do I have to phrase it differently?

*(Also if you could provide a source for your explanation that would be highly appreciated)*

Comment: Both are possible: See here: [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gestured+to+them+to+follow%2Cgestured+them+to+follow&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Comment: "gesture **to**" and "gesture **for**" are two examples of POSSIBLE PREPOSITIONS that can occur between the verb ***to gesture*** and the (direct or indirect) ***object*** of that verb. So what does **and "gesture prep."** mean in your question text? There are other possible prepositions, obviously *(He gestured **towards** me, She gestured **at** me to shut up I gestured **with** my finger,...)*

Comment: Gestured *them* means **to them**, an indirect object, but avoids the to-to repetition.

Comment: Do any dictionaries say that the verb 'gesture' has valid transitive usages? Do any indicate that targets (such as persons) rather than say 'his disapproval' fill DO slots? The 'gestured NP to V' construction is harder to find, but is, as @BillJ shows, not uncommon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: the OED does: "To express by gestures ... *1890   Pall Mall Gaz.* He..gestured his intention of throwing the baby to the ground if anybody attempted to approach him." Of course, this is a different meaning than the one the OP is asking about, and covers your example of "He gestured his disapproval."

Comment: @Yosef The dative transformation/shift (She gave a box **to him** ↔  She gave him a box) is of course well known, involving a preposition deletion to the 'DOC'  ('double object construction' ('to' in prototypical cases; 'for' in benefactives). But the result is the DOC, [NP.DATIVE] [NP]. Is there any literature you know of examining the 'advise / told / asked / ?gestured /?motioned / *indicated / *intimated ... to-inf structure (where the to ... to-inf  string is often retained)?